# How to store data into aerospike using nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, aerospike

I tried to add a CSV file into aerospike using nodejs with the `put()` command. It is showing all records but storing only last record. I need to store the entire CSV file into aerospike using client node js.

```
client.put(key, rec, function (error) {
if (error) {
    console.log('error: %s ', error.message)
}
else {
    console.log('Record %d written to database successfully.',count)
}
```

How to store a CSV file in aerospike using client nide js?

Comment: Does the csv have duplicate rows? Is the key used unique per rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a repeated action if I understand it correctly. The problem is that since `key` remains unchanged, `put` will override it, the last overrides the penultimate, the penultimate its previous, etc. You will either need to have multiple different keys and use those or inside the loop concatenate your texts and use `client.put` after the loop, but with the concatenated string.

Answer (score 1):

Another option for loading CSV files would be to use the Aerospike Data Loader tool: https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-loader.